# Организация фильтров выборки. Построение ЧПУ. PHP MVC

Tags: меню, php, фильтры, чпу, mvc

Итак. Имеется интернет магазин на php, при разработке использовался паттерн mvc.
Ссылки в меню в виде products/filters/category=название&type=название
Возникает проблема, когда нужно добавить в фильтр еще и что-то, например производителя, и все это компоновать.

```
Например у меня есть следующее меню :
Типы:
products/filters/category=категория1&type=тип1
products/filters/category=категория1&type=тип2
products/filters/category=категория1&type=тип3

Производители:
products/filters/category=категория1&producer=производитель1
products/filters/category=категория1&producer=производитель2
products/filters/category=категория1&producer=производитель3
```

В общем ссылки красивые, парсить удобно, но выходит что выбрать я могу что-то одно. Либо производителя, либо тип. А мне еще нужны ссылки в виде

```
products/filters/category=категория1&type=тип1&producer=производитель1

Например сначала я нажал на 
products/filters/category=категория1&type=тип1,
а потом на 
products/filters/category=категория1&producer=производитель1
И должен перейти на 
products/filters/category=категория1&type=тип1&producer=производитель1
```

Может тогда лучше формировать их где-нибудь отдельно, например в сессии или просто в отдельном массиве?
Благодарю за ответы.

Comment: > но выходит что выбрать я могу что-то одно 

 Поясните этот момент

Comment: Извиняюсь что сразу непонятно описал, добавил уточнение